# bitcoin.rpc python library problem

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, python, bitcoin-cli

I am working through Master Bitcoin. I got the `bitcoin client` up and running. I am now trying to access the client from `python`. In the example, there is a line that says `from bitcoin.rpc import Rawproxy`.

I get the error message `no module named rpc`. When I run `pip freeze`, I have `python-bitcoinrpc==1.0` listed. Why can't this module be found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in debian =)

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

pip install python-bitcoinlib 
 or 
pip3 install python-bitcoinlib

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Can I ask how you knew this? there seems to be no association to the library name in `import` and what you install. I looked everywhere online trying to figure out the library.

Answer (score 0):

bicoinlib is the module you try to use to handle bitcoind, bitcoin-cli in python,  rpc module is part of bitcoinlib.

libssl-dev is needed to handle SSL and TLS cryptographic protocols .

if bitcoinlib not work in newer bitcoin core versions 0.15 or newer just use raw bitcoinrpc.authProxy module.

Answer (score 0):

First, install libssl-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Install python3-pip if not yet:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Lastly, install python-bitcoinlib:

```
pip3 install python-bitcoinlib
```

In the example code, it is

```
info = p.getinfo()
```

Ran the example, I got "bitcoin.rpc.JSONRPCError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'Method not found'}"

Change it to:

```
info = p.getblockchaininfo()
```

(see https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/blockchain/getblockchaininfo/)

It works fine. I got the total number of blocks. In my case, it is 682903.